# USB keeps resetting randomly

Tags: ubuntu, usb, dmesg

I'm having weird problem with USB on my Linux Mint. It constantly resets some of my USB devices. What's weird is the fact that even the device that kernel chooses to reset is random.. sometimes it's mouse, sometimes headphones (keyboard seems to work perfectly so far), no matter if they're connected into the same port/hub as always or if I connect them somewhere else.

Add to it the fact that I've started having problems with my mouse reconnecting for some time (unfortunately I can't recall when was the first time..) - headphones worked okay, and suddenly - they started to reset too..

I doubt it's hardware related, I didn't notice the same problems on Windows and I've even hooked up my scope into my mouse's lines - couldn't spot anything irregular.

The device is random, timing is random, sometimes it works for hours, sometimes it resets my mouse like 10 times in a row (which is frustrating at least.)

I've read somewhere that it may be caused by auto-suspend, but I've already disabled it - resetting still occurs.

Mint version: 20

Kernel: 5.4.0-54-generic

What's very weird to me is the fact how random it is - from the logs you can see it kept resetting headphones first and suddenly - it switched to mouse... but when I've changed the mouse - suddenly it stopped. For a while at least.

dmesg log:

```
[lis26 06:50] usb 1-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[  +0,500645] usb 1-1.2: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=4096), cval->res is probably wrong.
[  +0,000002] usb 1-1.2: [11] FU [Sidetone Playback Volume] ch = 1, val = 0/4096/1
[lis26 06:51] usb 1-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[  +0,503009] usb 1-1.2: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=4096), cval->res is probably wrong.
[  +0,000006] usb 1-1.2: [11] FU [Sidetone Playback Volume] ch = 1, val = 0/4096/1
[ +16,528616] usb 1-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[  +0,506050] usb 1-1.2: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=4096), cval->res is probably wrong.
[  +0,000006] usb 1-1.2: [11] FU [Sidetone Playback Volume] ch = 1, val = 0/4096/1
[ +21,013533] usb 1-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[  +0,498049] usb 1-1.2: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=4096), cval->res is probably wrong.
[  +0,000004] usb 1-1.2: [11] FU [Sidetone Playback Volume] ch = 1, val = 0/4096/1
[  +5,931351] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[  +0,055363] usb 1-1.2: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=4096), cval->res is probably wrong.
[  +0,000003] usb 1-1.2: [11] FU [Sidetone Playback Volume] ch = 1, val = 0/4096/1
[ +39,027173] usb 1-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[  +0,501731] usb 1-1.2: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=4096), cval->res is probably wrong.
[  +0,000004] usb 1-1.2: [11] FU [Sidetone Playback Volume] ch = 1, val = 0/4096/1
[lis26 06:53] usb 1-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[  +0,505174] usb 1-1.2: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=4096), cval->res is probably wrong.
[  +0,000005] usb 1-1.2: [11] FU [Sidetone Playback Volume] ch = 1, val = 0/4096/1
[ +28,418650] usb 1-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[  +0,497563] usb 1-1.2: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=4096), cval->res is probably wrong.
[  +0,000004] usb 1-1.2: [11] FU [Sidetone Playback Volume] ch = 1, val = 0/4096/1
[lis26 06:55] usb 1-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[  +0,497451] usb 1-1.2: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=4096), cval->res is probably wrong.
[  +0,000006] usb 1-1.2: [11] FU [Sidetone Playback Volume] ch = 1, val = 0/4096/1
[  +1,374538] usb 1-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[  +0,505505] usb 1-1.2: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=4096), cval->res is probably wrong.
[  +0,000004] usb 1-1.2: [11] FU [Sidetone Playback Volume] ch = 1, val = 0/4096/1
[lis26 06:56] usb 1-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[  +0,505278] usb 1-1.2: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=4096), cval->res is probably wrong.
[  +0,000008] usb 1-1.2: [11] FU [Sidetone Playback Volume] ch = 1, val = 0/4096/1
[ +38,658840] usb 1-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[lis26 06:57] usb 1-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[  +1,364033] usb 1-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[ +14,546142] perf: interrupt took too long (2503 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79750
[lis26 06:58] usb 1-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[  +1,448068] usb 1-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[lis26 07:00] usb 1-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[  +1,324005] usb 1-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[  +1,363852] usb 1-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[  +1,724124] usb 1-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[lis26 07:01] usb 1-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[  +1,292083] usb 1-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[  +1,684031] usb 1-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[  +1,960067] usb 1-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[lis26 07:02] usb 1-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[  +1,303862] usb 1-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[  +1,472042] usb 1-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[ +35,578818] usb 1-1.2: 1:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x81
[  +0,359287] perf: interrupt took too long (3132 > 3128), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 63750
[  +7,458298] usb 1-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[  +3,063974] usb 1-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[lis26 07:04] usb 1-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[  +1,679997] usb 1-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[lis26 07:05] usb 1-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[  +1,603950] usb 1-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[lis26 07:06] usb 1-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[  +1,232031] usb 1-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[lis26 07:07] usb 1-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[  +1,304003] usb 1-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[  +1,304062] usb 1-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[  +1,508186] usb 1-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[  +1,371905] usb 1-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[  +1,324106] usb 1-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[  +1,236063] usb 1-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[  +1,452062] usb 1-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[  +1,671876] usb 1-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[  +1,360192] usb 1-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
```

And yes, the problem occurs even with headphones disconnected..

Can you please help me with finding the cause of it? Which logs would have more info?